# Connect to OrientDB using Gremlin.Net

Tags: c#, orientdb, tinkerpop3

Hi I'm trying to connect to **Orient.DB** (Community 3.0.18) with gremlin support from a easy console application and **Gremlin.net**.

I'm using the standard demodb. I can't get any gremlin query run, I get:

> ResponseException: ServerSerializationError: Error during
>   serialization: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)

This is my code:

```
        var gremlinServer = new GremlinServer("localhost", 8182, enableSsl:false,  username: "root", password: "xxxx");

        using (var gremlinClient = new GremlinClient(gremlinServer, new GraphSON2Reader(), new GraphSON2Writer(), GremlinClient.GraphSON2MimeType))
        {
            var query  = "g.V(\"33:5\")";

            // Create async task to execute the Gremlin query.
            var resultSet = gremlinClient.SubmitAsync<dynamic>(query).Result;
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

I also tried *GraphSON3Reader* and *GraphSON3Writer* having the same result.

I have two big doubt:

1) How to let this work

2) How can I specify the database? for example on CosmosDB you have to specify it in the user parameter, I tried also this solutino but again no luck.

Comment: what happens if you send a more simple script of "1+1"? do you get a result?